Why is my WhoID not pre-populated when creating a task for opportunity
I have a custom field on opportunity SalesContact__c which I want to use to pre-populate the WhoId field on task. It does not get pre-populated but after insert the field is filled. Why does it not pre-populate?
Here is my apex code in my tasktriggerhandler
public void beforeInsert(List<sObject> newList) {
    Set<Id> opportunityIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (sObject obj : newList) {
        Task task = (Task)obj;
        if (task.WhatId != null && String.valueOf(task.WhatId.getSObjectType()) == 'Opportunity') {
            opportunityIds.add(task.WhatId);
        }
    }
    
    Map<Id, Opportunity> opportunityMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, SalesContact__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :opportunityIds]);

    for (sObject obj : newList) {
        Task task = (Task)obj;
        if (task.WhatId != null && String.valueOf(task.WhatId.getSObjectType()) == 'Opportunity' && opportunityMap.containsKey(task.WhatId) && opportunityMap.get(task.WhatId).SalesContact__c != null) {
            task.WhoId = opportunityMap.get(task.WhatId).SalesContact__c; 
        }
    }
}


What's the question behind this question? See the X-Y Problem. While this code is not optimized, it should work as written.

@sfdcfox I do not see the field getting filled before save. I am expecting the value being filled before the insert. What am I missing?

@Thomas that is not how Salesforce works. Apex code, even code that runs beforeInsert ALWAYS runs on save. Save execution in Salesforce has multiple contexts, some are before and others are after, but they all happen after you hit the Save button. You'd need to use something other than Apex to solve this problem if you need it populated before save. Something like a screen flow, a new custom Action button, Lightning Component, or Visualforce.

You've written code in Apex, which, in a Trigger/Save Execution context, always runs after you hit the Save button. None of your code will execute on the screen before a user invokes DML.
Apex has a number of different Trigger Contexts, and if you are new to the language I'd recommend you spend some time on Apex Basics & Database.
In your case, since you are trying to manipulate the UI before saving a record, you'd need to look at a UI-specific customization option:
You could consider...

Creating a Custom Quick Action on the Opportunity object to create the Task, and using the Predefined Field Values list to populate the value when that action is pressed.
Creating a custom action that launches a screen flow, and then using the screen flow to collect/populate data before inserting the Task in the flow
Creating a Lightning Component or Visualforce page that recreates this process

These are high level examples intentionally to avoid doing the groundwork for you, but should be enough information to get you on the right track.
